# $P\left((A\cup B)(A\cup B^\complement)(A^\complement\cup B)\right)$ has the value

Tags: probability

If $A$ and $B$ are two independent events such that $P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(B)=\frac{2}{3}$,then $P\left((A\cup B)(A\cup B^\complement)(A^\complement\cup B)\right)$ has the value equal to 
$(A)\frac{1}{3}\hspace{1cm}(B)\frac{1}{4}\hspace{1cm}(C)\frac{1}{2}\hspace{1cm}(D)\frac{2}{3}$

---

$P\left((A\cup B)(A\cup B^\complement)(A^\complement\cup B)\right)$
$=P(A\cup B).P(A\cup B^\complement).P(A^\complement\cup B)$
$=(P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B))(P(A^\complement)+P(B)-P(A^\complement)P(B))(P(A)+P(B^\complement)-P(A)P(B^\complement))$

I put $P(A)=\frac{1}{2},P(B)=\frac{2}{3},P(B^\complement)=\frac{1}{3},P(A^\complement)=\frac{1}{2}$

but i am not getting the correct answer.Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Draw a venn diagram, two circles intersecting each other. Mark the 4 disjoint regions as p,q,r,s or whichever alphabets you like! Then write down the elements in each of the following (A ∪ B), (A’ ∪ B), (A ∪ B’) and see what's common in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $A \cup B$, $A \cup B^c$ and $A^c \cup B$ will (in general) not be indepedent, hence multiplicativity will not hold. But note that 
$$ (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup B^c) = A \cup (B \cap B^c) = A $$
hence
$$ (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup B^c) \cap (A^c \cup B) = A \cap (A^c \cup B) 
  = (A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B) = A \cap B $$
As $A$ and $B$ are independent 
$$ P \bigl((A \cup B) \cap (A \cup B^c) \cap (A^c \cup B)\bigr) = P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) = \frac 13. $$